# Creating new shapefile layer using multi line geometry but not accepting label using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, labeling

I am using QGIS.

I created a new shapefile layer using multi-line geometry, which won't accept a label.  I highlight the layer, toggle the edit button, open the properties box, open labels, activate single label, go to the text area and enter required text hit apply. Nothing happens.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: Did you use single quotes for your text? e.g. `'This is my label'`. _Btw, edit mode is not required to add a label._

Comment: If you want to add the content of an attribute field as a label, you don't have to type it - simply select it from the `Value` dropdown list. Like this you avoid syntax and typing errors. If it doesn't work, please add a screenshot that shows your `Value` dropdown list.

Comment: I didnt know you could type in the Value field... I always use attributes from the attribute table to lable the features